# Found: T[], required: T[]

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, generics

I have coded the sorting algorithm *Quicksort* in generic methods, with parameters:

- Partition method: (`T[] array, int low, int high`)
- Sorting method: (`T[] array, int low, int high`)

However, when I try to do recursion in the sorting method body, for the array parameter, I get this error:

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'T[]', required: 'T[]'

This is the code in the sorting method:

```
 if (low < high)
        { int pi = partition(array, low, high);
            Quicksort(array, low, pi-1);
            Quicksort(array, pi+1, high);
        }
```

---

Here's the code in partition method:

```
T pivot = array[high];
        int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
        {
            if (array[j].compareTo(pivot) <=0)
            {
                i++;
                // swap array[i] and array[j]
                T temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        // swap array[i+1] and array[high] (or pivot)
        T temp = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = array[high];
        array[high] = temp;

        return i+1;
```

---

I am confused how I can try to fix the compiler error. I tried casting it as `(T)array`, but it says the same thing. In my opinion, it wants the parameter as in `array[index]` form, but that makes my method inefficient.

Is there any suggestion how I can fix this error?

---

Here's my full code:

```
public class DD_ObjectBinarySearcher<T> {
    //comparison count for Binary search
    static int binarycount = 0;
    //comparison count for Sequential search
    static int seqcount = 0;
    //comparison totals for calculating averages
    static int stotal; static int btotal;

    /**
     *
     * @return total counts of Sequential Search
     */
    public static int getStotal() {
        return stotal;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return total counts of Binary Search
     */
    public static int getBtotal() {
        return btotal;
    }

    /**
     * @param array array to be sorted
     * @param low starting index
     * @param high ending index
     * @return partition for quick sort
     */
    static  <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] array, int low, int high)
    {
        T pivot = array[high];
        int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
        {
            if (array[j].compareTo(pivot) <=0)
            {
                i++;
                // swap array[i] and array[j]
                T temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        // swap array[i+1] and array[high] (or pivot)
        T temp = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = array[high];
        array[high] = temp;

        return i+1;
    }

    /**
     * @param array array to be sorted
     * @param low starting index
     * @param high ending index
     */
    static <T> void Quicksort(T[] array, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        { int pi = partition(array, low, high);
            Quicksort(array, low, pi-1);
            Quicksort(array, pi+1, high);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param a array
     * @param b compared integer
     * @return flag
     */
    static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean sequentialSearch(T[] a, T b){
        for (T i : a) {
            if (i==b){
                System.out.println("The number of comparisons for unsorted array: " + seqcount);
                stotal+=seqcount;
                return true;
            }
            seqcount++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param a array
     * @param b compared integer
     * @return flag
     */
    static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean binarySearch(T[] a, T b) {
        if (a.length == 0) return false;
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length-1;

        while(low <= high ) {
            int middle = (low+high) /2;
            if (b.compareTo((T) a[middle]) > 0){
                low = middle +1;
            } else if (b.compareTo((T) a[middle]) < 0){
                high = middle -1;
            } else { // the element has been found
                System.out.println("The number of comparisons for sorted array: " + binarycount);
                btotal+=binarycount; //totals are used to calculate average in the main
                return true;
            }
            binarycount++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param array that will be printed
     */
    static void printArray(int[] array)
    {
        for (int value : array) System.out.print(value + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: According to Java coding conventions, classes (and their constructors) should begin with a capital letter; methods and variables should begin with a lower case letter. Because of this I was wondering why you were calling the Quicksort constructor twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2 different generic methods involved here each defined a type parameter `T`.  The `T` in `Quicksort` doesn't have any bounds, so it doesn't have to be `Comparable` at all.  However, the `T` in `partition` needs to have an upper bound of `Comparable<T>`.  The compiler error doesn't tell the entire reason, but the error shows up because the `T` bounds don't match.

Make your `T` bound in `Quicksort` the same bound.

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> void Quicksort(T[] array, int low, int high)
```

Usually for flexibility we take this idea one step further, because Consumer Super (from PECS):

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void Quicksort(T[] array, int low, int high)
```

which you should add to all your `T` bounds, including the one for `partition` and any others that need a bound.

Because all your methods are `static`, the `T` defined on the class isn't even used.  You can safely remove it.

```
class DD_ObjectBinarySearcher {
```